# wordpress, cron & time - does time on server affects plugins? how to fix it? (virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, cron, wordpress, time, virtual-machines

I'm running wp on lamp install in virtual machine. I frequently pause it, save snapshots, etc. Date and time aren't correct because of this and i think i noticed weird behavior of plugins that use cron. How do i fix my time and plugins? Maybe i should get time from external location so it would be correct even though i regularly pause my machine?

It's Debian Lenny guest on other linux host. I'm using virtualbox.

Comment: what virtualization technology are you using?

Comment: virtualbox (hmmm 15 characters minimum ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is Time Synchronization, which is a feature of the Guest Additions in Virtual Box. Looks like it wasn't installed. From the Virtualbox manual:

> Time synchronization With the Guest
>   Additions installed, VirtualBox can
>   ensure that the guest’s system time is
>   better synchronized. This fixes the
>   problem that an operating system
>   normally expects to have 100% of a
>   computer’s time for itself without
>   interference, which is no longer the
>   case when your VM runs together with
>   your host operating system and
>   possibly other applications on your
>   host. As a result, your guest
>   operating system’s timing will soon be
>   off significantly. The Guest Additions
>   will re-synchronize the time
>   regularly.

Install instructions [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#id2508055).

Answer (score 2):

To syncronise time, use NTP (Network time protocol).

Firstly, sync time with

`sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

Then, install ntpd 
`sudo apt-get install ntp`

Comment: This isn't really what you want. You want your host machine synchronized with NTP and you want your guest synched to your host. Otherwise, they guest time will be jumping all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

VMs don't always play well with ntp.

If you are using VMware, install the VMware tools. Then, there is a setting in the `.vmx` file called `time.syncTime` that should be set to `TRUE` (although the time seems to be staying sync'd since I install VMware Tools even set to the default `FALSE`).

Here are some other VMware settings:
(from http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_timekeeping.pdf):

- `tools.syncTime` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs periodically.
- `time.synchronize.continue` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs after taking a snapshot.
- `time.synchronize.restore` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs after reverting to a snapshot.
- `time.synchronize.resume.disk` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs after resuming from suspend and after migrating to a new host using the VMware VMotion feature.
- `time.synchronize.shrink` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs after defragmenting a virtual disk.
- `time.synchronize.tools.startup` If set to `TRUE`, the clock syncs when the tools daemon starts up, normally while the guest operating system is booting.

Answer (score 0):

```
man 8 hwclock
```

or add this to root's crontab in the virtual machine

```
*/1 * * * *  hwclock --hctosys
```

Comment: but hardware clock will be guest 'hardware' clock, i guess? so not what i'm looking for?